# Play music (song album or artist) with variables in AppleScript

Tags: variables, applescript, itunes

I'm making trying to make an apple script that understands a text command "Play song We will Rock You" or "Play artist Queen" or "Play album A Night at the opera"

using songName artistName and albumName as variables, but i don't know how to set them, as they depend on the previuos word (song,artist,album) in an answer which is "Play song songName" (PLAY must be in the field).

I know how to make them play I just need to set those variables in order to use just one textfield.

Thanks for you help (hope I was clear)

Comment: Always include your own code. We like to see some code so that we know you've tried to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set xxx to text returned of (display dialog "Play song, Play artist, Play album " buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" default answer "Play song Here I Come")

set myChoices to {"Play song ", "Play artist ", "Play album "}

tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with i from 1 to count myChoices
        set aChoice to (item i of myChoices)
        if xxx starts with aChoice then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to aChoice
            set theRest to text items 2 thru -1 of xxx
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
            set theRest to theRest as text

            if i = 1 then
                play (first track whose name = theRest)
            else if i = 2 then
                play (first track whose artist = theRest)
            else if i = 3 then
                play (first track whose album = theRest)
            end if
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get input:

```
display dialog "Enter the album name:" default answer "CocoaRocks"
set the albumName to the text returned of the result
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to use ONE text to control to control "Play song songName" "play artist ArtistName" "play album albumName". that's why I have troubles

Comment: So you need to parse a string like "Play song My heart is singing" or "Play album Singing Hearts" so you can isolate the song- or album title to send to iTunes. Is that it? (BTW: good resource here: http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/index.html )

Answer (score 0):

Heres something similar, plays a mp3 file

`set audioFile to (POSIX path of (choose file of type "mp3"))
do shell script "afplay " & audioFile`